# Last digit of $235!^{69}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, factorial

**Problem**

What is the last digit of $235!^{69}$?

It's been far too long since I did any modulo calcuations, and even then, the factorial would set me back.

My initial thought goes to the last digit $5$ in $235$. If $235!$ can be shown to have a $5$ as last digit, raising it to any natural number shouldn't change that, right?

Comment: Your initial thought is good but could have been followed up with "is it possible for any factorial to be odd?"  That nicely eliminates the possibility of it ending in 5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is zero. Actually $n!$ is a multiple of $10$ for $n\ge 5$, and raising a multiple of $10$ to any natural power results in a multiple of $10$ again.

---

To elaborate, $235!$ ends in $\lfloor\frac{235}5\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{235}{25}\rfloor+\lfloor\frac{235}{125}\rfloor+\ldots = 57$ zeroes, hence $235!^{69}$ ends in $57\cdot 69=3933$ zeroes.
The last *non-zero* digit of $235!$ turns out to be a $6$ (however, showing that is not *that* trivial), and for that your argument applies that this does not change by raising to natural powers (because already $6\cdot 6\equiv 6\pmod{10}$. We conclude that the last non-zero digit of $235!^{69}$ is a $6$.

Comment: So painfully obvious once it's been pointed out. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If $n>4$, then $(n!)^k \equiv 0\mod{10}$ $\implies$ the last digit is a $0$.

To see this, note since $n>4$, $n!=(n)(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)$. We can rewrite this as: $$10\cdot[(n)(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(4)(3)(1)]$$ Now our modulo definition states that since 10 is a factor of $n!$, taking its mod will yield a zero remainder ($\exists h\in \{1,2,3...\}$ s.t. $h=\frac{n!}{10}=\frac{10\cdot[(n)(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(4)(3)(1)]}{10}=[(n)(n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(4)(3)(1)]$ which is natural number since the naturals are closed under addition and multiplication). Thus, we have proven $n!$'s congruence to $0\mod10$. Now we simply note the following identity:

If $a\equiv b\mod{m}$, then $a^q\equiv b^q\mod{m}$.